# matlab: changing the layer of patches and lines

Tags: matlab

According to [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-3Y3C84/?solution=1-3Y3C84):

> If a line is coplanar with a patch or surface and the zbuffer or OpenGL renderer is being used, the lines appear on top.

The relative arrangement of a `line` and `patch` object cannot be modified by `uistack` function (e.g., `uistack(patchHandle,'top')` and `uistack(lineHandle,'bottom')` do not change the layer of one object relative to the other). Can a `line` be forced to reside in a lower layer than a `patch` without selecting an alternative renderer?

Answer (score 1):

Graphics objects are stacked based on their order in `get(gca,'children')` (first element = top, last element = bottom), so rearranging that array allows you to change the layer of lines, patches, etc.

Example:

```
patch([0.25 0.25 0.75 0.75],[0.25 0.75 0.75 0.25],'y')
hold on;
plot([-1 1],[-1 1],'b-',[1 -1],[-1 1],'r-','linewidth',10)
```

Currently from bottom to top: patch, blue line, red line

[image: Original order]

```
g=get(gca,'Children')
g=g([3 1 2])
set(gca,'children',g)
```

Now bottom to top: blue line, red line, patch

[image: Patch on top]

```
g=get(gca,'Children')
g=g([1 3 2])
set(gca,'children',g)
```

Now bottom to top: red line, blue line, patch

[image: Blue over red]